# How to replace the values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajaxSetup ({  
    cache: false  
  }); 
  setTimeout(getData, 5000);
});


/* call the php that has the php array which is json_encoded */
function getData(){
  $.getJSON('api.php', function(data) {
    $('ul').empty();
    /* data will hold the php array as a javascript object */
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      $('ul').append('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.date + ' ' + val.event + ' ' + val.region + ' ' + val.host + ' '+ val.type + ' ' + val.info + '</li>');
    });
    setTimeout(getData, 5000);
  });
}
```

Output:

> 2016-09-09 09:12:18 **WARN** MRP SIU05 [main] Started, locked port 7075

How to replace (`val.event`) the occurrence of WARN on WARN2?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What did you try yourself?

Comment: I need to make to replace the value "val.event"

Comment: $(...).val($(...).val().replace("a","b"))

Comment: Where do you get "WARN2" values?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```js
//Here value is val.event
//value = val.event
var value = 'WARN2';
value = value.replace(value,'WARN');
console.log(value);
```